Source code to KDE's "Charge Limit"
KDE's system settings has a section "Power Management > Advanced Power Settings > Charge Limit" where there's 2 options "Stop charging at:" and "Start charging only once below:"
I need to know what variable/program in the system it actually calls to make this change, to be able to do the same via the terminal (as part of some handy scripts and shortcuts).
I have an obscure platform (Macbook Air M2 2022 running Debian Asahi Linux) so the regular commands on settings charge limit that are vendor specific or ACPI/BIOS are unfortunately inapplicable, however whatever it is KDE does works perfectly. I just need to know how I can do the same via a console command.
My guess is KDE does something to some systemd service. When it asks for user password, the program mentioned is org.kde.powerdevil.chargethresholdhelper.setthreshold
